# Adding a third tab view in xcode 6.2 or 6.3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, viewcontroller

I have trawled the internet and can see how to add a new scene to the storyboard by dropping a tab bar item into the new controller and then creating a segue from the main tab bar controller to my new view. I have then added labels and run the project in the simulator.
But when I add a button in the storyboard scene, where is the associated view controller file? How do I create it or select it in order to enter my buttons functions?

Comment: can you please clarify where you are trying to add button in the storyboard ??

Comment: the button will go in the new storyboard controller (picture of iphone)

Answer (score 2):

Adding a view controller to the storyboard does not generate code. You will want to create a custom class for each view controller. In order to do that you will need to follow the images below.

1. [image: Adding View Controller 1]
2. [image: Adding View Controller 2]
3. [image: Adding View Controller 3]
4. [image: Adding View Controller 4]

After you have done that you will see the new class for the final view controller on the left with all your other classes. You then need to connect the class to your view controller.

5. [image: Connecting Class to Controller 1]
6. [image: Connecting Class to Controller 2]

Comment: Basically, I have created a new view and now have a tab controller controlling 3 screens. But where is the code for screen 3 in order for me to place an IBaction for my button which now only appears on the storyboard

Comment: The above steps are how to create the class to put your code for your ibaction. You have to create the class and link it to the third view controller to get it to appear.

Comment: If you are new to iOS development you may want to start with some online training such as sites like http://teamtreehouse.com or look at tutorials on http://raywenderlich.com . The above example will create the class which is where you put your code for the third view controller.